# TFS 2015 - tfpt Create new Team Project

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

Trying to create a powershell script to create a new project in Team Foundation Server 2015.

When running the script I get the message:

> The project collection does not have a default location for creating
>   project portal sites configured.  Either configure this location using
>   the Team Foundation Administration Console or specify the
>   /webapplication and /relativepath arguments.

Any suggestions, I want to create a new git repository instead of needing to use Visual Studio.

My create new project script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string]$name
)
Write-Host "Create new project: $name";
tfpt createteamproject /collection:'http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection' /teamproject:"$name" /processtemplate:'scrum' /sourcecontrol:'NewGitRepo'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create a new Git repository, there's no need to create a new Team Project. You can add as many Git repos as you want to a single project.

In the web portal, visit the "Code" tab, click on the active repository (in the top left) and click on the "New Repository" button.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Daniel Manns answer:

You can add new repositories to an existing Team Project from the project administration page using the New Repository button

> http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/[CollectionName]/[ProjectName]/_admin/_versioncontrol

There does not seem to be any way to create a new Team Project nor add a new repository using TFPT, but the latter is possible thanks to this:

[TfsGitAdmin](https://github.com/giuliov/TfsGitAdmin)

You will end up with a repo url something like

http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/[CollectionName]/[ProjectName]/_git/[NewProjectName]

---

<strike>One (possibly major) downside to adding a repository this way is that it doesn't seem to be accessible to Code Reviews, at least not in TFS 2013.</strike>

The new repository is a bit difficult to find through the Portal interface. It's hiding under the (usually redundant) Team Project dropdown.

[image]

This is the same in TFS 2015

Answer (score 1):

just add the /noportal parameter, which indicates that the project does not require site in Sharepoint.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need details for the SharePoint configuration. Try to run the script with adding arguments?
[/webapplication:http://sharepoint.domain.local] and [/relativepath:/sites/DefaultCollection/MyProject].
You can checkout [msdn site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386357(v=vs.110).aspx) and [an old but still relevant blog](http://blog.codeblack.nl/post/TFS-2010-Moving-Sharepoint-to-another-server.aspx)

Comment: But if I don't want to use SharePoint? I would like to create a new team project with a GIT repository as I would in Visual Studio. Is that not possible?