# Error in creating new projects in online TFS using my account

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

This is a different issue as I am accessing and using my visualstudio.com server. Please see the image.
I am currently working on an automation in powershell which is to create a new project in VSTS using my account. Unfortunately, I am having an error which is below.

> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: The project collection does not have a default location for creating project portal sites configured.
>   Either configure this location using the Team Foundation Administration Console or specify the /w
>   ebapplication and /relativepath arguments.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2015 - tfpt Create new Team Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671586/tfs-2015-tfpt-create-new-team-project)

Comment: this is a different issue. as I am accessing it using visualstudio.com. to add I am using Visual Studio

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? You can add new repositories to an existing Team Project from the project administration page ...

Comment: Yes I have tried it but with no luck. have you tried to try to add using your visualstudio.com account.

Comment: @JedidiahAmmielJimenez  Which method are you using in your powershell to create team project, Rest API or tfpt? Could you directly share your powershell script(cover your personal information) here?

Comment: I am using tfpt.

Comment: Used Rest API instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tfpt only works with TFS2015 or more older version. It does not work with VSTS and TFS2017.
[image]

You can use Rest API to create the team project via script just as you found. Or you can also consider to use the VSTS CLI: [VSTS Create Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/project?view=vsts-cli-latest).

Comment: Thanks for the answer how can you create a project there. I have logged in the account with my token but still it does not create a project.

Comment: @JedidiahAmmielJimenez Can you share the command format you use?